# Integrity constraint (LEETO14.SYS_C00414504) violated

Tags: mysql, database, oracle

I can't figure out why I'm getting this error:

```
integrity constraint (LEETO14.SYS_C00414504) violated - parent key
```

not found

Everything works up until the insert values for CurrentLoan. Here is my code:

```
CREATE TABLE Book
(bookID INT PRIMARY KEY,
ISBN INT,
title varchar (20),
author  varchar (20),
publish_year INT,
category varchar(20)); 

CREATE TABLE Member
(memberID INT PRIMARY KEY,
lastname varchar (20),
firstname varchar (20),
address varchar(20),
phone_number INT,   
limit_ INT);

CREATE TABLE CurrentLoan
(memberID INT,
bookID INT,
loan_date DATE,
due_date DATE,
PRIMARY KEY (memberID, bookID),
FOREIGN KEY (memberID) REFERENCES Member(memberID),
FOREIGN KEY (bookID) REFERENCES Book(bookID));

INSERT INTO Book VALUES (10, 1113312336, 'The Dog', 'Jack Crow', 1990, 'fiction');
INSERT INTO Book VALUES (12, 2221254896, 'Worms', 'Jim Kan', 2013, 'fiction');
INSERT INTO Book VALUES (13, 3332546987, 'Crow', 'Jan Flo', 2000, 'fiction'); 
INSERT INTO Book VALUES (14, 4443456215, 'Big Dog', 'Lan Big', 1993, 'fiction'); 
INSERT INTO Book VALUES (15, 5552314569, 'Green Apple', 'Theo Brown', 1978, 'fiction');
INSERT INTO Book VALUES (16, 6664581631, 'Red Bean', 'Khang Nk', 2017, 'fiction');
INSERT INTO Book VALUES (17, 7771452369, 'The Dark Car', 'Author Le', 2017, 'fiction');
INSERT INTO Book VALUES (18, 8881245525, 'The Dark Room', 'Jack Se', 2017, 'fiction');
INSERT INTO Book VALUES (19, 9991123546, 'Lonely Mens', 'Geen Brown', 2014, 'fiction');
INSERT INTO Book VALUES (20, 1122112356, 'The Big Tree', 'Heart Le', 2002, 'fiction');

INSERT INTO Member VALUES (001, 'Lee', 'Nancy', 'Brownlea Drive', 1254896325, 2);
INSERT INTO Member VALUES (002, 'Le', 'Ray', '10th Street', 1234561256, 2);
INSERT INTO Member VALUES (003, 'Kan', 'Charlie', '5th Street', 1234567236, 2);
INSERT INTO Member VALUES (004, 'Brown', 'Joe', 'Elm Street', 1234567845, 2);
INSERT INTO Member VALUES (005, 'Smith', 'John', '33 East', 1234567890, 2);

INSERT INTO CurrentLoan VALUES (00123, 0236, '13-SEP-17', '14-NOV-17');
INSERT INTO CurrentLoan VALUES (00134, 2350, '13-JAN-17', '15-NOV-17');
INSERT INTO CurrentLoan VALUES (00125, 2034, '14-FEB-17', '12-MAR-17');
INSERT INTO CurrentLoan VALUES (00345, 0105, '12-OCT-17', '09-NOV-17');
INSERT INTO CurrentLoan VALUES (00311, 5012, '13-APR-17', '12-MAY-17');
INSERT INTO CurrentLoan VALUES (00213, 2051, '11-JUN-17', '02-OCT-17');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is pretty self explanatory. You have foreign keys in the table, *CurrentLoan*. Looking at your insert statement, you're trying to add loans for members that you have not created and books you have not created.

Comment: Could you show an example or fix one of my code? Sorry, I'm new to this so I'm not exactly sure what you mean by that.

Comment: @tubvajlis: When you have a foreign key in *CurrentLoan* that references *Member*, you can't enter a member id into *CurrentLoan* that doesn't exist in *Member*.

Comment: @tubvajlis: Your first column in both the Member and CurrentLoan insert statement is the member id. Notice how there's no commonality between those numbers?

Comment: @tubvajlis: Same issue with the books

Comment: okay, so what I did was remove the primary keys and foreign keys from CurrentLoan. That seem to work. But, is it okay to remove it?

Comment: Depends on if you need the foreign keys to maintain data quality. They're a good thing to have, but they aren't necessary.

Comment: Ah, I understand now..Thank you very much

Comment: @tubvajlis - generally speaking, it's a very bad idea to remove constraints in order to make code 'work'. By dropping the constraints you're creating problems which will bite you later. The fix here is to add the needed data, not to drop the constraints.

Comment: @BobJarvis yes and thank you, I went back and fix my inserts and added the primary keys and foreign keys.